# Variable Lenghts Differ using the glm fuction in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a model selction. I am using cbind for two variables (no, yes). However, when I do this, I get the 'variable lengths differ' error.
I have done the model regression without the cbind & only using the variable LD with no issues.I cannot seem to find a way to change my code to be able to do this.

Here is my code

```
blh <- read.table('Data.dat', header=T)

blh$Level <- factor(blh$Level, labels=c('0','1','2'))
blh$Male <- factor(blh$Male, labels=c('female','male'))
blh$Night <- factor(blh$Night, labels=c('day','night'))
blh$Wet <- factor(blh$Wet, labels=c('dry','wet'))
blh$LD <- factor(blh$LD, labels=c('no','yes'))
ftable(xtabs(Count~Level+Male+Night+Wet+LD, data=blh))

fit <- glm(cbind(no,yes)~ Level+Male+Night+Wet, data=blh,family=binomial)
```

My dataframe looks like this if that would help.

```
                       LD no yes
Level Male   Night Wet          
0     female day   dry     3  12
                   wet     2  13
             night dry     2  13
                   wet     3  12
      male   day   dry    12  30
                   wet     9  33
             night dry    11  31
                   wet    15  27
1     female day   dry    12  36
                   wet     4  20
             night dry    11  37
                   wet     1  23
      male   day   dry    27  39
                   wet    10  23
             night dry    30  36
                   wet    10  23
2     female day   dry     9  27
                   wet     5  13
             night dry     8  28
                   wet     2  16
      male   day   dry    24  60
                   wet    15  27
             night dry    30  54
                   wet    13  29
```

Comment: Please save the RStudio tag for cases where RStudio is part of the problem - like if your code doesn't work in RStudio but does work on the command line.

Comment: Could you please share with sample data `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable? The data you show has a bunch of missing entries and it's not clear if they are empty strings `""` or whitespace `"   "` or missing values `NA` or something else...

Comment: Here it is structure(list(Level = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L), Male = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Night = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Wet = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), LD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Count = c(3L, 
12L, 9L, 12L, 27L, 24L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: That looks good for those variables - and there's no blanks so that's good! There's no `yes` and `no` variables in that data - I would recommend adding those columns to this data set. If you have all the variables in the same data frame, then they should have the same length.

Comment: You could also check `length(no)` and `length(yes)` and compare to `nrow(blh)`. They need to be the same.